# Database User Interface Design Process

Tags: project-management, project-planning

I am the only developer at my organization and am expected to develop databases and interfaces to those databases. Developing online front-ends using web frameworks is time-consuming. Do other people in this situation usually write a text-based interface to the database to perfect access and update methods, or is  web-based CRUD the usual solution?

Comment: It's hilarious that people are digging through questions asked in 2010 looking for things to downvote and close. Do you not have anything better to do with your time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your users. Tech savy or nubs? High pressure environment or casual? Heavy keyboard users or do they reach for the mouse at every chance they get? etc etc

Design around their needs, and ideally design around their tasks. A simple CRUD based approach may be fine for your userbase and problem domain, or it may be a cumbersome choice. Truthfully in my experience CRUD is rarely the right way to go - it mirrors your data model, and let's be fair, data models are never designed around user expectations or usecases.

Spend a little time getting to know your userbase - designing UIs is so much easier once you do.

Fluffy answer, but there really is no true answer :)